How to Ensure "Completed" Log Appears After Entire Orchestration Sequence in Durable Functions
I'm working on a Durable Functions setup where I have a timer trigger orchestrating a sequence of activities. However, I'm facing an issue with the logging sequence. Currently, the "Completed" log appears immediately after the timer trigger, but I want it to appear only after the entire orchestration sequence, including all sub-orchestrations, is completed. Below is a simplified version of my code:


[Function("TimerTrigger_EveryMinute")]
public async Task TimerTrigger_EveryMinute(
    [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Running timer trigger");

    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("MainOrchestrator", null);

    // Wait for the entire orchestration to complete
    await starter.WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(instanceId);

    _logger.LogError($"Completed timer trigger orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'");
}

[Function("MainOrchestrator")]
public async Task MainOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Running MainOrchestrator");

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    List<TransactionData> transactions = new List<TransactionData>();

    // Call suborchestrator for each ongoing transaction
    foreach (var transaction in transactions)
    {
        tasks.Add(context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestrator", transaction));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

[Function("SubOrchestrator")]
public async Task SubOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, TransactionData transaction)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Running SubOrchestrator");

    // other logic here
}


In this setup, the logs are showing "Completed" immediately after the timer trigger logs, but I want it to appear only after all orchestrations, including sub-orchestrations, are completed.

That is quite odd. I tested this locally with .NET 8 isolated and logging happened after the orchestrator had fully completed (and the sub-orchestrator was done).

I have modified your code a bit and it worked as expected.
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Transactions;

namespace _78332074
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("TimerTrigger_EveryMinute")]
        public async Task TimerTrigger_EveryMinute(
        [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Running timer trigger");

            string instanceId = await starter.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("MainOrchestrator", null);
            await starter.WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(instanceId);

            _logger.LogError($"Completed timer trigger orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'");
        }

        [Function("MainOrchestrator")]
        public async Task MainOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Running MainOrchestrator");

            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            tasks.Add(context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestrator", null));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        [Function("SubOrchestrator")]
        public async Task SubOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context, TransactionData transaction)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Running SubOrchestrator");
        }
    }
    public class TransactionData
    {
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }
}

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78332074</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.2.0-rc.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I am getting below output.


The MainOrchestrator function seems to be invoked multiple times in quick succession, leading to unexpected behavior in my application. I expect it to be invoked only once per timer trigger. Could someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can ensure that the MainOrchestrator function is invoked only once per timer trigger?

@Sandeep It invokes 2nd time after the completion of  sub orchestrator in the same way it will also invoke for a activity completion if any. This is an expected behavior of durable function, refer to my answer in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232392/azure-durable-functions-powershell-strange-orchestrator-behavior/78237296#78237296
